# Regular Expressions: RegEx for determining valid PHP class property names?

Tags: php, regex, oop

I am using PHP's magic `__set` and `__get` methods to access a private array in a class. Use of the class can include "setting" new properties as well as using existing ones. I want to make sure the property names created or requested (i.e. `$myObj->FakeProperty`) are valid according to the following rules:

1. Property names must begin with either a letter or underscore [A-z_]
2. If it begins with an underscore, it must be followed by a letter
3. So long as the first two rules are met, the name may contain any of [A-z0-9_]

My current RegEx isn't doing the trick; with my test values, `_12` always falls through the cracks.

**Test Fields:**

```
albert12
12Albert
_12
_Albert12
_12Albert
_____a_1
```

**RegEx:**

```
^(?=_*[A-z]+)[A-z0-9_]+$
```

Comment: Do you want to allow only those identifiers that are also allowed in class definition, like `public $identifier;`? There are other ways to define (public) properties, e.g. `$x = new StdClass; $x->{'  12'}=12; var_dump($x);` is valid and working. And exactly why do you want to test them first? Either they are present/declared/defined or they are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), the following would match any valid php identifier

```
/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$/
```

Comment: Assuming this is going to be used with preg_match, don't forget the `D` modifier.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it was helpful.. I had forgotten about that page in the docs. I'm toning it down a bit, but this is the solution I'll be using. Thanks stereofrog.

Answer (score 4):

`/^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]+$/i`

Comment: That works, and its basically just what I'll be using. You and stereofrog effectively provided the same answer, but I gave it to sf for providing the link to the official docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness' sake, you should be aware that you can create properties with just about anything in the name, although it will probably break other stuff later. Consider the following *working* example:

```
class Test {
    function __construct() {
        $this->{" `~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{},./?;:'\""} = "Don't try this in production code.";
    }
}

var_dump(new Test);
```

Comment: I'm doing this primarily to allow convenient access to simple database fields names. I don't care about (and frankly would prefer to avoid) really complex identifiers, just simple ones like `$myObj->simpleVar`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but __get and __set are only triggered when you already tried to access a syntactically valid propertyname that is unavailable via the object's public API. If you want to make sure the element you are trying to access exists in the private array, use `array_key_exists`:

```
class Foo {
    protected $data = array(
    'bar' => 'baz'
    );
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
        throw new BadMethodCallException('Invalid property');
    }
}

$obj = new Foo;
$obj->123; // Syntax Error => __get won't be called
$obj->foo; // valid syntax, but not in array => BadMethodCall Exception
$obj->bar; // returns baz
```

Comment: I also allow "new" properties to be set this way, so I'm trying to catch valid identifiers in the "__set" rather than the "__get".

Comment: Oh, and I'm sure you're right that get and set wouldn't let you create an invalid variable anyway, so I could just leave it alone in my case. But the scenario pointed out by <i>too much php</i> is also a concern; I'd rather block crazy property names, which the regex will also assist with. Thanks for your help.